# how to Select until "this" with Jquery (or CSS5)

Tags: jquery, css, select

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody id="example">
        <tr>
            <td>cell-1</td>
            <td>cell-2</td>
            <td>cell-3</td>
            <td>cell-4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, for example, if mouse is over cell-X then I want to select all cells from 1 to X

Like this:

```
$('tr > td','#example').mouseover(function(e) {
    //select cells begining from first to $(this)
});
```

OR is this possible with CSS5 ?

Comment: Great question, however you are missing the biggest detail.. what are you trying to accomplish using this selection code?  (Just jQuery, change CSS, etc)

Comment: I didn't understand your question ? I want to "select until this" either in Jquery or in CSS

Comment: Tell me: what is CSS5?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$('tr > td','#example').mouseover(function(e) {
    // Remove .selected from All <td />
    $('tr > td','#example').removeClass('selected');

    // Look Through All <td /> Until Reaching Current
    var el = $(this).get(0);
    $('tr > td','#example').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        if ($(this).get(0) == el){
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

The `.selected` class is only for illustration purposes. You can replace it with whatever functionality you need.

JSFiddle Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6Wp8d/).

**Edit**

The following would also work if you were looking to do something simple with the element or as part of a jQuery chain.

```
$('tr > td','#example').hover(
    function (){
        var elIndex = $('tr > td','#example').index(this);
            elIndex += 1; // To Include Current Element
        $('tr > td','#example').slice(0, elIndex).addClass('selected');
    },
    function (){
        $('tr > td','#example').removeClass('selected');
    }
);
```

Edited Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6Wp8d/1/).

I hope this helps!